# Filter by two tagging systems

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, relational-database

I have a `post` relation and `tag_system_one` and `tag_system_two`.

There is a many-to-many relationship between `post` and `tag_system_one` through `tag_system_one_post`.

There is a many-to-many relationship between `post` and `tag_system_two` through `tag_system_two_post`.

I would like a SQL query for multi tag search.

When there is only one tag system the query is pretty simple:

```
SELECT post.*
FROM post
JOIN tag_system_one_post ON post.id = tag_system_one_post.fk_post
JOIN tag_system_one ON tag_system_one_post.fk_tag_system_one = tag_system_one.id
WHERE tag_system_one.id IN (500, 533)
GROUP BY post.id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

In this example, it retrieves all posts with the two tags `500` and `533` (intersect).

```
Posts that only have tag `500` but not `533` will not be shown.
```

I am able to enforce the above statement because I am using `COUNT(*) = 2`. But this will not work when I introduce another tagging system (`tag_system_two`).

Is there a way to do this without a subquery?

Answer (score 0):

After thinking a while I think the solution is:

```
HAVING COUNT(*) = 
no. of items selected in tagging_system_one 
MULTIPLIED BY
no. of items selected in tagging_system_two
```